Why I can not define some method as "protected" in interface declaration?
On Laravel 10 site defined an Interface class I got error :

Access type for interface member must be omitted

when I define some method as "protected":
namespace App\Library\Services\Interfaces;

interface PostRatingInterface
{
    public static function calc(int $postId): float;

    protected static function getMembershipMarkValue(): float;

Does it mean that I have to define all interface methods as "public" - or omit it because it would be the same "public"?
"php": "8.2",
"livewire/livewire": "^3.4.10",


Interface can only have public methods, as it's contract on what methods are awailable to be called from outside
